# Delete multiple lines from files using sed/awk using regex pattern

Tags: regex, sed, awk

Eclipse's "Generate Entities from Tables..." JPA code generator insists on creating an @Id field and associated getter/setter methods, despite the fact that these are defined in the superclass I designate in the wizard steps.

To work around this, my idea is to write a script to remove the offending lines and clean up the generated files in other ways.  (Yes, I could do this manually using the Find/Replace dialog in Eclipse, but I want to automate the entire set of changes because I'll be doing this code generation/clean up routine multiple times while working on various models.)

The problem is that I cannot find the right regex pattern for matching multiple lines for use in either awk or sed. The regex patterns I create work in Eclipse's and TextWrangler's search dialogs, but not with awk or sed.

Here are the multi-line pieces of text I want to remove (in **separate** calls to awk/sed, of course):

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private String id;
```

and

```
    public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Please note that each non-empty line in the cited code above begins with a \t character, even though it's not present when pasted here.

As an example, to delete the getter/setter lines, I have tried

```
awk '!/\tpublic String getId\(\) \{\r\t\treturn this\.id;\r\t\}\r\r\tpublic void setId\(String id\) \{\r\t\tthis\.id = id;\r\t\}\r/' $file > temp.txt && mv temp.txt $file
```

or a shortened version

```
awk '!/^\tpublic String getId.*\r.*\r.*\r\r.*\r.*\r.*\r\r/' ...
```

but neither work.

(Both patterns work in Eclipse or TextWrangler to find the lines to be removed.)

I can only get single line deletes, for example

```
awk '!/^\tpublic String getId.*\r/' ...
```

but that's not helpful, since deleting "\t}\r" would delete all method-ending and class-ending curly braces.

I'm doing this on a Mac running OS X 10.8.2, if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, awk and sed are line-based tools, so you can't match against more than one line.

I would suggest identifying the range using a regex for the first line and an offset to the last line, like this:

```
sed -e '/^\tpublic String getId/,+2 d'
```

This deletes the line `public String getId`, and the two following lines.

Comment: Thanks for trying but here's what I get for an error message:   `sed: 1: "/^\tpublic String getId ...": expected context address` and `
sed: 1: "/@Id/,+4 d": expected context address`    for   `sed -e '/^\tpublic String getId/,+2 d' $file`   and   `sed -e "/@Id/,+4 d" $file`  Is it possible that this is due to the version of sed on OS X 10.8.3?

Comment: Yeah, I guess the +2 is a GNU extension. You could try matching the ending line with a regex as well: `/regex1/,/regex2/`.

Comment: Thanks, I came across the same info (GNU version) after adding my comment.  Indeed, using two addresses (two regex patterns) as you suggest does trick in the BSD version on OS X. (It turns out, while waiting for some suggestions here, I wrote an Applescript which does the file massaging -- it uses TextWrangler's replace function with the regex patterns in my original question above.  That works fine, too.)